# How to create a Scatter Plot in google sheets API in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm having problems creating a scatter plot in Google sheet API in Python. I've already been able to create the new sheet but with NO DATA. Also, I'm not sure I am adding the necessary number of variables for the scatter plot.

I've ran a test on updating the information in a new sheet and it did work well but I'm still having problem on creating a new chart

Here is my code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

## The ID spreadsheet

```
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'Wl4g72ovwE_H0IH3unrtt0oTr5shWFY'
sheet_Id = '1005435407'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

## Call the Sheets API

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
```

## Chart

```
request_body = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "addChart": {
        "chart": {
          "spec": {
            "title": "Categorical Expenses",
            "basicChart": {
              "chartType": "SCATTER",
              "legendPosition": "BOTTOM_LEGEND",
              "axis": [
                  # X-AXIS
                {
                  "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                  "title": "Clusters"
                },
                  # Y-AXIS
                {
                  "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                  "title": "Dimensions"
                }
              ],
              # Chart labels
              'domains': [
                  {
                      'domain': {
                          'sourceRange': {
                              'sources': [
                                  {
                                      "sheetId": sheet_Id,
                                      "startRowIndex": 0, # Row # 1
                                      "endRowIndex": 1001, # Row # 1000
                                      "startColumnIndex": 9, # Column J
                                      "endColumnIndex": 10 # Column K
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      }
                  }
              ],
                "series": [
                    {
                        "series": {
                            "sourceRange": {
                                "sources": [
                                    {
                                        "sheetId": sheet_Id,
                                        "startRowIndex": 0, # Row # 1
                                        "endRowIndex": 1001, # Row # 1000
                                        "startColumnIndex": 9, # Column J
                                        "endColumnIndex": 10 # Column K
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS"
                    }
                ]
            }
          },
            "position": {
            "newSheet": True
            }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
            
response = sheet.batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        body=request_body).execute()

print('chart created successfully')
```

Comment: I think that in your question, it is required to confirm your current Spreadsheet for replicating your issue. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet as an image?